# Why does SQL Import Wizard think that my Excel data is 255 characters long?

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to import a data sheet into SQL, and I have several columns that I've limited the length of the data on. The Wizards keeps giving me a warning that says:

Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Technology Platform" with a length of 255 to database column "TechnologyPlatform" with a length of 15.

The columns cells are all exactly 10 characters in length, and I have limited the text length of those columns in excel to 10 characters. So why does SQL think that these are 255 characters long? Like I said, I have other columns limited and they are importing just fine.

Comment: I suspect the difference between this and the columns where you aren't getting warnings is on the SQL side: TechnologyPlatform is limited to 15 characters. Are the other fields that you are importing into limited? Also, this is just a warning. Emphasize the words "may occur." If your data fits, then don't worry about the warning.

Comment: To add to what @JamieF said, Excel cells can only hold 255 characters each cell, so SQL might see them defined as VARCHAR(255) and you're importing it to a column TechnologyPlatform which, as Jamie stated, is defined as VARCHAR(15), which is probably why you get the warning.

Comment: Hi Jamie, Thanks. Yes, I have other fields that are limited, and even if I select to ignore truncation errors it still fails

Comment: @joseph4tw i dont think that is true. ive had many thousands of characters in each cell

Comment: @user699242 good point!  I completely confused cell contents for a different Excel limitation.  My bad!